# php code for monitoring a license expiration and notify the admin about a month before

Tags: php, html

I need a php code to monitor the expiration dates of the license of different registered workers. 
Also the admin needs to be notified whenever one of the workers' license is soon or has already expired for them to send an email to this worker..

here's the codes I've made so far..(but the notification part isn't in here yet, i'm trying to focus first on the start and expiration date.)thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could'nt connect to db");
mysql_select_db("tesda") or die ("cant connect");
$table = 'exdates';

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>untitled</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"
        });
    };
</script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>

<body>
<?php
$start = $_POST['startdate'];
echo 'Date(license received): ';
echo date("m - d - Y".$start);

$monthAgo = date("m/ d /Y",strtotime('+3 years'));
echo ' your license will expire on: '.$monthAgo;

if(date($monthAgo)=='-1 month'){
echo 'Your License will expire in 1 month!';}
?>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

I wanted the start of date to be manually encoded in the database but the expiration date will be based on that adding three years.. when I tried this, the startdate is the same with the computers date, and has added 3 years for the expiration date..but, my problem is when i tried changing the date of the computer, the startdate also changes as well as the expiration date..how will it expire if it keeps on changing everytime the calendar in this computer changes? what should I do? thanks! :)

sorry, it seems that i've made you confused..what i'm trying to say is.. I'll put the start date in the databse, using php I just want to get that date and be posted in the website and also using php, i'll add 3 yrs for the expiration date.. with this codes i have posted, the startdate keeps on adjusting with the calendar date of this computer..because of this, the expiration date also moves and adjusts..what i'm refering with this is, if I put the startdate as 10-10-2012, when i reload/reopen it on the following days, it'll stay as 10-10-2012 and will expire on 10-10-15..and not adjust to the current date..today, the startdate shows, 10-12-2012 and will expire 10-12-2015 but with this codes, tomorrow, the stardate will change into 10-13-2012 and will expire on 10-13-2015.. see, it keeps on adjusting,how on earth will it expire if its always like that..Please, I really need your help.. I keep on editing it myself but I just can't do it.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your date calculations:

```
<?php
$start = $_POST['startdate'];
echo 'Date(license received): ';
echo date("m - d - Y".$start);

$monthAgo = date("m/ d /Y",strtotime($start.' +3 years'));
echo ' your license will expire on: '.$monthAgo;

if(strtotime($monthAgo)<=strtotime('-1 month')){
echo 'Your License will expire in 1 month!';}
?>
```

Comment: I edited my questions already..I also added a few more explanations...kindly read it again..thanks! :)

Comment: Please, reply again sirs/ma'ams..I really need your help.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your question that you don't want the customer to be able to change their computer time to alter their license period. If that's the case then you should grab the date from your own server in the PHP script to check against their subscription time.

You can use cURL or file_get_contents to pull the date by calling a page on your server that simply displays the date.

```
<?php
$date = file_get_contents("http://www.yoursite.com/datecheck/customer1234.php");
?>
```

Compare and output your message.

Comment: I edited my questions already..I also added a few more explanations...kindly read it again..thanks! :)